# Convert to DateFormat

Tags: date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with dateformat is in ddmmyyy and I would like to change it to yyyymmdd. I have to change it with an update using the to_char statement. What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

please use this format for update

```
to_char(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```